# Proxmox - virtual machine behind NAT

Tags: proxmox

I have Proxmox with 1 public IP. I have some OpenVZ containers with Internet behind NAT.

I want to create VM, but when I have set NAT Mode in VM, I got IP 10.0.0.X by DHCP. Containers have 192.168.0.X .
When I set up on VM to f.e. 192.168.0.230, I have lost connection with Internet and containers are not vissible too.

How can I set up VM to have Internet and visible behind NAT on IP 192.168.0.X ?

I've tested with bridged with vmbr1, but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need 2 Network Adapters 1 Public 1 for Local , 
your VM running under Private and your Proxmox Vm running Public IP 
sample : https://your-public-ip:8006 
Adapter 2 is only for setup your virtual machine 
recommend install windows machine on the private  , Openvz ls light weight kernel , for full virtual machine recommend KVM